# jQuery Validate MultIple File Upload

Tags: php, jquery, file, validation, upload

I am trying to validate a HTML file upload using jQuery Validate plugin,

My html form is,

```
<form id="formid" action="welcome/test_up" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="myfile[]" id="myfile" multiple>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
```

And I'm using Jquery validation plugin as,

```
$('#formid').validate({
    rules: { 
       inputimage: { required: true, accept: "png|jpe?g|gif"  }
    },
    messages: { inputimage: "File must be JPG, GIF or PNG" }
});
```

But unfortunately it's not working,

It's working if I use `name="myfile"` but not when I use `name="myfile[]"`

Any idea to solve this ?

Comment: This may not have anything to do with your JS, but with the actual PHP.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this ? because i've completed my php  scripts with php validation but my client needs some realtime validation. So any idea ?

Comment: I'd have to see your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

try to set your rule in input tag become

```
<input type="file" name="myfile[]" id="myfile" accept="png|jpe?g|gif" multiple>
```

so your js only

```
$('#formid').validate();
```